# MySQL Creat View with all data where date is max

Tags: mysql, database, select, join, max

I want to create a view which combines the data with the maximal date from the tables shown in the picture. These should be grouped by the profileID.

[Database ERM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdmBg.png)

The profileIDs are linked to profile.userID.

I tried different approches in my code. The fort one slects the data where date is max, but the join doesn't work. Every profileID will be joined with the same data.

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `b91788dd8d05b5`@`%` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
```

VIEW `fitchallengersql1`.`profileview` AS

```
Select p.userID,
(SELECT 
            `bf`.`bodyFat`
        FROM
            (`fitchallengersql1`.`bodyfatprofile` `bf`
            JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`profile` `p`)
        WHERE
            ((`bf`.`profileID` = `p`.`userID`)
                AND (`bf`.`date` = (SELECT 
                    MAX(`fitchallengersql1`.`bodyfatprofile`.`date`)
                FROM
                    `fitchallengersql1`.`bodyfatprofile`)))) AS `bodyFat`,
    (SELECT 
            `bw`.`bodyweight`
        FROM
            (`fitchallengersql1`.`bodyweightprofile` `bw`
            JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`profile` `p`)
        WHERE
            ((`bw`.`profileID` = `p`.`userID`)
                AND (`bw`.`date` = (SELECT 
                    MAX(`fitchallengersql1`.`bodyweightprofile`.`date`)
                FROM
                    `fitchallengersql1`.`bodyweightprofile`)))) AS `bodyWeight`,
    (SELECT 
            `bmi`.`bmi`
        FROM
            (`fitchallengersql1`.`bmiprofile` `bmi`
            JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`profile` `p`)
        WHERE
            ((`bmi`.`profileID` = `p`.`userID`)
                AND (`bmi`.`date` = (SELECT 
                    MAX(`fitchallengersql1`.`bmiprofile`.`date`)
                FROM
                    `fitchallengersql1`.`bmiprofile`)))) AS `bmi`

        From profile
```

In the second one the join works how it should, but I can't figure out a way to select just the data where date is max.

```
    CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `b91788dd8d05b5`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `fitchallengersql1`.`profileview` AS
    SELECT 
        `p`.`userID` AS `userID`,
        `p`.`privacy` AS `privacy`,
        `bs`.`size` AS `bodysize`,
        `bw`.`bodyweight` AS `bodyweight`,
        `bf`.`bodyFat` AS `bodyfat`,
        `bmi`.`bmi` AS `bmi`
    FROM
        ((((`fitchallengersql1`.`profile` `p`
        JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`bodysizeprofile` `bs`)
        JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`bodyweightprofile` `bw`)
        JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`bmiprofile` `bmi`)
        JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`bodyfatprofile` `bf`)
    WHERE
        ((`p`.`userID` = `bs`.`profileID`)
            AND (`p`.`userID` = `bw`.`profileID`)
            AND (`p`.`userID` = `bmi`.`profileID`)
            AND (`p`.`userID` = `bf`.`profileID`))
```

Hope someone could help me.

Thank you!

fleewe

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope following query gives what you need. Please follow the pattern and join the rest of the tables. Please note that when the table grows these will definitely have performance issues as this require huge processing.

```
-- Select the columns that you need
select p.*, lbp.*
from profile p
inner join (
        -- get the latest bmiprofile per user profile
        select bp1.*
        from bmiprofile bp1
        inner join (select profileID, max(date) as date from bmiprofile group by profileID) as bp2 on bp1.prfileId = bp2.profileId and bp1.date = bp2.date

    ) as lbp on lbp.ProfileId = p.userId
-- Join the other tables in similar way
```

Comment: Thank you!
This would work for me. The only issue is, that MySQL doesn't accept a subquery in the From-part in a View.
I worked around with using more than one view but I think I have to figure out an other solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is only a comment, but I needed formating capability:

Don't place the joining predicates into the where clause if using ANSI join syntax, instead use `ON` followed by the relevant predicates. e.g.

```
  FROM `fitchallengersql1`.`profile` `p`
        JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`bodysizeprofile` `bs`   ON `p`.`userID` = `bs`.`profileID`
        JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`bodyweightprofile` `bw` ON `p`.`userID` = `bw`.`profileID`
        JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`bmiprofile` `bmi`       ON `p`.`userID` = `bmi`.`profileID`
        JOIN `fitchallengersql1`.`bodyfatprofile` `bf`    ON `p`.`userID` = `bf`.`profileID`
```

Comment: Thank you!
I adjusted my views like this.